# Removing Ubuntu from a laptop and install Windows 7

Tags: windows, drive

This may have been asked before, but I can't seem to find an appropriate answer. I've been searching for about two days now, to no avail. Here is my situation. 
I purchased a new laptop. The original thought was to put Ubuntu on first, that put on Windows 7, which I have. After I installed Ubuntu, It wouldn't let me install windows. After a while, I got frustrated and decided to REMOVE Ubuntu and just install Windows 7 for a class i'm going to need in a few days. For the life of me, I can't uninstall Ubuntu. I've tried everything possibe and even google searched. I purchased WipeDrive, still not working. Tried to restart and boot from disk. It freezes. Sometimes only sees Ubuntu on C drive and not my cd drive. Please, for the love of god, help me get Ubuntu off of my computer. Please.

Comment: And for your next attempt to install Ubuntu (alongside Windows if you wish): https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu

Comment: Ubuntu IS NOT AN APP! You can't just UNINSTALL it, you need to install windows over the disk so ubuntu is gone!

Answer (score 1):

You only need a DVD of Windows or a Live GParted to format your HDD.

1. Insert Windows DVD
2. Select install
3. Remove the existing partitions
4. Create new partitions for Windows
5. Format the partitions
6. Install Windows.